# Double integral of the product of exponential function and the power fucntion

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $H$ be (0,1), $\lambda>0$ and $-\infty \leq a<b \leq c<d<\infty$. How to simplify the following double  integral of the product of exponential function and the power fucntion:
$$
\int_{a}^{b} e^{\lambda u}\left(\int_{c}^{d} e^{\lambda v}(v-u)^{2 H-2} d v\right) d u .
$$

However when trying to further integrate I get absurdly long integrals with multiple levels of integration by parts required which makes me think I am overcomplicating the problem. Let $x=v-u$, I have

$$
\int_{a}^{b} e^{\lambda u}\left(\int_{c}^{d} e^{\lambda v}(v-u)^{2 H-2} d v\right) d u =
\int_{a}^{b} e^{2\lambda u}\left(\int_{c-u}^{d-u} e^{\lambda x}x^{2 H-2} d x\right) d u .$$

If anyone could shed some light on how to approach such an integral that would be amazing. The result of any special functions are also welcomed.

Comment: This looks to require the incomplete gamma function.